# How do i find the standard deviation score for all values in R?

Tags: r, standard-deviation

For example i have a mean based on function mean(value)= 1.278394 and i have a standard deviation for the values at .8028161

I would basically like the dataset to look like this

```
  value| sd score
1.278394       0
2.0812101      1
.4755779      -1
2.8840262      2
1.67980205   0.5
```

I guess you can call this sd score?

Comment: I have a column with a set of values. If i run sd(values) i get the whole SD. If i run mean(values) i get the whole mean. What I want is to create a second column that gives me the value of sd score. Every row will have its own value and the sd score will say if its 1 sd,2 sd, 2.1, 3.5 sd away from the mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"z score" is the common term for the number of standard deviations from the mean. You can calculate this easily for a vector, either manually or with the scale function:

```
my_mean = 1.278394 
my_sd = .8028161
x = rnorm(10, my_mean, my_sd)
z_score = (x - my_mean) / my_sd

# the scale function does this for you
scale(x, my_mean, my_sd)
```

If you don't supply the mean and sd, scale will calculate it based on the x values. So in your data frame you can do something like:

```
my_data$z_score = scale(my_data$value)
```

and the `scale` defaults will do what you want.

Comment: Yes. Exactly. Thank you.